# Laravel keyBy() interfering with orderBy() Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I'm using the Collection method keyBy() to return data keyed by the ID of the records, which is very helpful. But unfortunately this seems to interfere with the orderBy() query builder method.

```
    $laptops = Laptop::filterResults($request)->addJoins()->selectListCols()->paginate(50);
    $laptopsCollection = $laptops->getCollection()->keyBy('id');
    $laptops->setCollection($laptopsCollection);
```

In the below, the `filterResults()` may include an `orderBy()` clause, which works fine and sorts the resultset as expected, UNTIL I add the bottom two lines, where I get the collection and key it by ID. How can I do both - order the query builder results and key the resulting collection by ID?

Comment: It would be more helpful to provide the error you receive, and dump of the data returned in both cases with and without `orderBy`

Comment: `orderBy()` is for which **key/attribute**, also `ascending` or `descending`?

Comment: @MinaAbadir There is no error - the problem is the records are returned in the wrong order, not obeying the `orderBy()` clause.

Comment: @prateekkathal Various - the `orderBy()` is supplied by the user, and may be either asc or desc.

Comment: I am unsure as to why `keyBy()` is changing the order of the collection. It shouldn't really do that. Can you edit your question and add a small sample to what you get from `$laptops->getCollection()` and `$laptops->getCollection()->keyBy('id')`?